# IHttpClient Polly Timeout and WaitAndRetry policy when handling concurrent http requests Clarification

Tags: c#, timeout, dotnet-httpclient, polly, retry-logic

Just have a question about Pollys timeout/retry policy and how it works when handling concurrent http requests.

From reading/my own understanding the timeout and retry policy will be applied to each individual http request, so if we have 5 http requests, each of them would have there own timeout and retry policy, so from the code below each http request would timeout after 5 seconds and retry a total of 4 times.

```
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        
        var timeout = Policy.TimeoutAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

        builder.Services
            .AddHttpClient("PointsbetClient")
            .AddPolicyHandler(GetRetryPolicy())
            .AddPolicyHandler(timeout);
    }

    private static IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> GetRetryPolicy()
    {
        return HttpPolicyExtensions
            .HandleTransientHttpError()
            .Or<TimeoutRejectedException>()
            .WaitAndRetryAsync(Backoff.DecorrelatedJitterBackoffV2(
                medianFirstRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500),
                retryCount: 4));
    }
```

Now say I have a 1000 http requests to which I need to make GetAsync() calls to so I can scrape their data and for performance purposes, I am making these calls concurrently, by using `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);`. Since 1000 is way too many requests to hit at the one time I am using `SemaphoreSlim` class and limiting the MaxParallelRequests to 100.

How would the Polly retry and timeout policy apply now? does it still apply to each of those individual 1000 requests or will it treat 1 task containing 100 requests as a single timeout/retry policy? From my understanding it would still treat and apply policy to each of the individual http requests, I've been searching but can't find confirmation on this.

Comment: Well, the short answer is that yes they are treated separetly. In case of Circuit Breaker or Bulkhead policy they aren''t separated because there is a shared Context under the hood. If you want I can leave tomorrow a detailed answer with source code links.

Comment: Okay thanks that would be perfect, yeah so im not using Pollys BulkHead policy I thought it was not designed for the purpose of handling/limiting mass amounts of concurrent requests for my case, a im always going to be need to hit 1000 http requests and i dont necessary what exceptions being thrown there when scraping data hence why i got my own SemaphoreSlim implementation, so from that id assume the policy will only be applied to individual http requests and not the overall Task.

Comment: Spoiler alert: The [bulkhead policy relies on SemaphoreSlim](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/174cc53e17bf02da5e1f2c0d74dffb4f23aa99c0/src/Polly/Bulkhead/BulkheadEngine.cs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is yes they are treated separately.

---

In order to understand how the system works we have to look under the hood. Let's start our journey at the `AddPolicyHandler`.

**Disclaimer**: *I've slightly edited the code snippets for the sake of brevity.*

```
public static IHttpClientBuilder AddPolicyHandler(this IHttpClientBuilder builder, IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> policy)
{
    if (builder == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));
    if (policy == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(policy));
    builder.AddHttpMessageHandler(() => new PolicyHttpMessageHandler(policy));
    return builder;
}
```

This method is defined inside the [`PollyHttpClientBuilderExtensions`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a450cb69b5e4549f5515cdb057a68771f56cefd7/src/HttpClientFactory/Polly/src/DependencyInjection/PollyHttpClientBuilderExtensions.cs#L31) class and it provides extension methods for the `IHttpClientBuilder`.

As you can see it does nothing else just registers yet another [`HttpMessageHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/httpclient-message-handlers) into the chain.

Now, let's see how does this special handler look like

```
protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (request == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(request));

    // Guarantee the existence of a context for every policy execution, 
    // but only create a new one if needed.
    // This allows later handlers to flow state if desired.
    var cleanUpContext = false;
    var context = request.GetPolicyExecutionContext();
    if (context == null)
    {
        context = new Context();
        request.SetPolicyExecutionContext(context);
        cleanUpContext = true;
    }

    HttpResponseMessage response;
    try
    {
        var policy = _policy ?? SelectPolicy(request);
        response = await policy.ExecuteAsync((c, ct) => SendCoreAsync(request, c, ct), context, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (cleanUpContext)
            request.SetPolicyExecutionContext(null);
    }

    return response;
}
```

This method is defined inside the [`PolicyHttpMessageHandler`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a450cb69b5e4549f5515cdb057a68771f56cefd7/src/HttpClientFactory/Polly/src/PolicyHttpMessageHandler.cs#L109).

As you can see nothing extraordinary happens here

- We either retrieve or create a new Context
- We either retrieve the policy from registry or use the provided one
- We execute the policy which decorates the `SendCoreAsync`

So, where does the magic happen? Let's jump to the [documentation comment](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a450cb69b5e4549f5515cdb057a68771f56cefd7/src/HttpClientFactory/Polly/src/PolicyHttpMessageHandler.cs#L61) of this class

> All policies provided by Polly are designed to be efficient when used in a long-lived way. Certain policies such as the
> Bulkhead and Circuit-Breaker maintain state and should be scoped across calls you wish to share the Bulkhead or Circuit-Breaker state.
> Take care to ensure the correct lifetimes when using policies and message handlers together in custom scenarios. The extension
> methods provided by `PollyHttpClientBuilderExtensions` are designed to assign a long lifetime to policies
> and ensure that they can be used when the handler rotation feature is active.

To understand how does Retry differ from Circuit Breaker lets look at their `Engine`s' `Implementation` signature

[RetryEngine](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/174cc53e17bf02da5e1f2c0d74dffb4f23aa99c0/src/Polly/Retry/RetryEngine.cs#L10)

```
internal static class RetryEngine
{
    internal static TResult Implementation<TResult>(
        Func<Context, CancellationToken, TResult> action,
        Context context,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken,
        ExceptionPredicates shouldRetryExceptionPredicates,
        ResultPredicates<TResult> shouldRetryResultPredicates,
        Action<DelegateResult<TResult>, TimeSpan, int, Context> onRetry,
        int permittedRetryCount = Int32.MaxValue,
        IEnumerable<TimeSpan> sleepDurationsEnumerable = null,
        Func<int, DelegateResult<TResult>, Context, TimeSpan> sleepDurationProvider = null)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

[CircuitBreakerEngine](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/174cc53e17bf02da5e1f2c0d74dffb4f23aa99c0/src/Polly/CircuitBreaker/CircuitBreakerEngine.cs#L9)

```
internal class CircuitBreakerEngine
{
    internal static TResult Implementation<TResult>(
        Func<Context, CancellationToken, TResult> action,
        Context context,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken,
        ExceptionPredicates shouldHandleExceptionPredicates, 
        ResultPredicates<TResult> shouldHandleResultPredicates, 
        ICircuitController<TResult> breakerController)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

What you have to spot here is the `ICircuitController`. The [`CircuitStateController`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/174cc53e17bf02da5e1f2c0d74dffb4f23aa99c0/src/Polly/CircuitBreaker/CircuitStateController.cs#L7) base class stores the state information. One of its derived class is [shared](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/174cc53e17bf02da5e1f2c0d74dffb4f23aa99c0/src/Polly/CircuitBreaker/CircuitBreakerPolicy.cs#L13) between the different policy executions

```
internal readonly ICircuitController<EmptyStruct> _breakerController;
...
CircuitBreakerEngine.Implementation(
    action,
    context,
    cancellationToken,
    ExceptionPredicates,
    ResultPredicates,
    _breakerController);
```

---

I hope this clarify things.