# Polly re-try policy not working in conjunction with circuit breaker with Ocelot

Tags: c#, polly, circuit-breaker, retry-logic, ocelot

I wanted to use `Polly` re-try and circuit breaker with `Ocelot` api gateway. I am trying to wrap policies with `DelegatingHandler`, the `circuit breaker` works, but `re-try` not works.

Below code just throw the exception, but NO re-try happening. When I am calling the API 3 times, circuit opens.

```
"ExceptionsAllowedBeforeBreaking": 3,
.CircuitBreakerAsync(route.QosOptions.ExceptionsAllowedBeforeBreaking,

[HttpGet("RaiseException")]
    public async Task<int> RaiseException()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);
        throw new Exception("Mock Exception");
    }
```

[pollyQosProvider](https://github.com/ThreeMammals/Ocelot/blob/develop/src/Ocelot.Provider.Polly/PollyQoSProvider.cs)

**Custom Handler:**

```
 public class PollyWithInternalServerErrorCircuitBreakingDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly IOcelotLogger _logger;
    private readonly Polly.Wrap.AsyncPolicyWrap<HttpResponseMessage> _circuitBreakerPolicies;
    public PollyWithInternalServerErrorCircuitBreakingDelegatingHandler(DownstreamRoute route, IOcelotLoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<PollyWithInternalServerErrorCircuitBreakingDelegatingHandler>();

        var pollyQosProvider = new PollyQoSProvider(route, loggerFactory);

        var retryPolicy = HttpPolicyExtensions.HandleTransientHttpError()
                            .OrResult(r => r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                            .WaitAndRetryAsync(2, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)));

        var responsePolicy = Policy.HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
            .CircuitBreakerAsync(route.QosOptions.ExceptionsAllowedBeforeBreaking,
                TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(route.QosOptions.DurationOfBreak));
        _circuitBreakerPolicies = Policy.WrapAsync(pollyQosProvider.CircuitBreaker.Policies)
            .WrapAsync(retryPolicy).WrapAsync(responsePolicy);
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            return await _circuitBreakerPolicies.ExecuteAsync(() => base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken));
        }
        catch (BrokenCircuitException ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Reached to allowed number of exceptions. Circuit is open", ex);
            throw;
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Error in CircuitBreakingDelegatingHandler.SendAsync", ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

**Ocelot Builder Extensions:**

```
public static class OcelotBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IOcelotBuilder AddPollyWithInternalServerErrorHandling(this IOcelotBuilder builder)
    {
        var errorMapping = new Dictionary<Type, Func<Exception, Error>>
        {
            {typeof(TaskCanceledException), e => new RequestTimedOutError(e)},
            {typeof(TimeoutRejectedException), e => new RequestTimedOutError(e)},
            {typeof(BrokenCircuitException), e => new RequestTimedOutError(e)}
        };

        builder.Services.AddSingleton(errorMapping);

        DelegatingHandler QosDelegatingHandlerDelegate(DownstreamRoute route, IOcelotLoggerFactory logger)
        {
            return new PollyWithInternalServerErrorCircuitBreakingDelegatingHandler(route, logger);
        }

        builder.Services.AddSingleton((QosDelegatingHandlerDelegate)QosDelegatingHandlerDelegate);

        return builder;
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        //Ocelot add it's configuration file
        builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile($"ocelot.config.{builder.Environment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
        builder.Services.AddOcelot(builder.Configuration)
            .AddPollyWithInternalServerErrorHandling();
```

**Ocelot Configuration**

```
 "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET" ],
  "QoSOptions": {
    //Number of exceptions which are allowed before the circuit breaker is triggered.
    "ExceptionsAllowedBeforeBreaking": 3,
    //Duration in milliseconds for which the circuit breaker would remain open after been tripped
    "DurationOfBreak": 5000,
    //Duration after which the request is considered as timedout
    "TimeoutValue": 100000
  }
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on *but re-try not works*? Does it throw an exception? Does it not perform any retry? Or what is the expected and observed behaviour?

Comment: Could you also please share with us the definition of pollyQosProvider.CircuitBreaker.Policies?

Comment: @PeterCsala, Thanks for your response. The re-try just not happening, but circuit opens after 3 exception as per configuration above.

Comment: @PeterCsala, here the the Ocelot library integrates Polly, no sure if they added any re-try feature out of the box? https://github.com/ThreeMammals/Ocelot/blob/develop/src/Ocelot.Provider.Polly/PollyQoSProvider.cs

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Ocelot`. What will happen if you call the `RaiseException` endpoint via `base.SendAsync`? Will you receive a `HttpRequestException` or a status code 500? Or something else?

Comment: no worries @PeterCsala. I have remove Oclelot Polly package and works with simple Polly and custom delegating handler. Works fines. Appreciate your time and help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the problem has been solved by removing Ocelot, let me share my thoughts about your policies.

---

#### The escalation policy

[The way how you chain the policies to each other defines an escalation order.](https://github.com/peter-csala/resilience-service-design/blob/main/resilience.md#esc)

So, first let's see how does your policy chain looks like.

[The `PollyQoSProvider` helper class](https://github.com/ThreeMammals/Ocelot/blob/develop/src/Ocelot.Provider.Polly/PollyQoSProvider.cs) defines two policies in the following order:

- A Circuit Breaker which triggers for `HttpRequestException`, `TimeoutRejectedException` and `TimeoutException`
- And a Timeout

These policies do not return any value.

You have defined two other policies:

- A Retry which triggers for `HttpRequestException` or when the status code is either 404 or 408 or 5XX
- A Circuit Breaker which triggers when the status code is 500

These policies do return with an `HttpResponseMessage`.

You have chained them in the following order (from the most outer to the most inner):

> Circuit Breaker which triggers for `HttpRequestException`, `TimeoutRejectedException` and `TimeoutException`
>
> > Timeout
> >
> > > Retry which triggers for `HttpRequestException` or when the status code is either 404 or 408 or 5XX
> > >
> > > > Circuit Breaker which triggers when the status code is 500

This may or may not be your desired resiliency strategy. I would advice you to reassess whether this is what you really want/need.

#### Chaining the policies

The policies of the `PollyQoSProvider` are defined for async methods (`Task`) whereas yours are defined for async functions (`Task<HttpResponseMessage>`). The static `WrapAsync` does not allow to combine these two types of policies. On the hand the instance level `WrapAsync` does. (For more information about this constraints please read [this SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73106630/13268855).)

Because you have used the combination of the two that's why the chained policy is an `IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>`. Even though it's working, I usually suggest to use only the static `WrapAsync` to chain policies due to its compile-time compatibility guarantees.

#### Multi level circuit breakers

I'm using Polly for awhile and I haven't encountered any use case where multiple (nested) circuit breakers would be really required. Most of time you can (and should) solve it with a single CB which can trigger for multiple different conditions:

> Circuit Breaker which triggers when the status code is 500 or for the following exceptions: `HttpRequestException`, `TimeoutRejectedException` and `TimeoutException`

```
Policy<HttpResponseMessage>
  .HandleResult(r => r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
  .Or<HttpRequestException>()
  .Or<TimeoutRejectedException>()
  .Or<TimeoutException>()
  .CircuitBreakerAsync(
```

#### Circuit breaker and its shared state

[The CB was designed in a way that it can be shared between multiple components](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72211805/13268855). If you have already detected that the downstream is temporarily inaccessible then use this information everywhere rather than issue new requests and come to the same conclusion.

So, defining a CB inside a `DelegatingHandler` is against this. Each and every `DelegatingHandler` will have its own CB so, they do not share state via the `ICircuitController`. Aim for reusing CB policy.

#### Timeout strategies

[Timeout can work in optimistic or in pessimistic mode.](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout#operation) Even though your code looks like at first glance it uses optimistic, unfortunately it does not.

```
protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        return await _circuitBreakerPolicies.ExecuteAsync(() => base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken));
    }
    ...
}
```

The proper way would be the following by using a different overload of `ExecuteAsync`:

```
await _circuitBreakerPolicies.ExecuteAsync((ct) => base.SendAsync(request,ct), cancellationToken);
```

OFF: The `PollyQoSProvider`'s CB was defined in a way that it can break for optimistic timeout (`TimeoutRejectedException`) and pessimistic timeout (`TimeoutException`) as well.